# Simulating intermittent network failures with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Running a test that has a long running (non-request/response action) along with polling to check the status.  While this polling is going on, I'd like to make a few packets disappear.  I keep seeing things that look like this might work with WebDriver only to come up short.  Is there anyway to do this completely inside of selenium or do I have to go to a completely external proxy?

My thoughts were to act like an ad blocker in that I could watch what was being requested and refuse certain connections and return things like 502s or return nothing at all.  But I'd like it to be under the control of the test, not an external setup.

Comment: I'm afraid Selenium itself does not support such options. I would use proxy to block or modify the responses. [This post](https://www.webelement.click/en/selenium_webdriver_java_simulate_network_connection_problem_with_browsermob-proxy) will probably give you some view on the relevant experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can manipulate requests by using a proxy. It's simplest to block requests. Depending on how your webapp is performing this might be a way to do it.
Check out Browsermob proxy usage:

Look here to get started: [URL blacklisting with BrowserMobProxy in Robot Framework/Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52699816/1387701)

```
// Start the server and get the selenium proxy object
ProxyServer server = new ProxyServer(proxy_port);  // package net.lightbody.bmp.proxy

server.start();
server.setCaptureHeaders(true);
// Blacklist google analytics
server.blacklistRequests("https?://.*\\.google-analytics\\.com/.*", 410);
// Or whitelist what you need
server.whitelistRequests("https?://*.*.yoursite.com/.*. https://*.*.someOtherYourSite.*".split(","), 200);

Proxy proxy = server.seleniumProxy(); // Proxy is package org.openqa.selenium.Proxy

// configure it as a desired capability
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);

// start the driver   ;
Webdriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

return driver;
```

But you should be able to dynamically configure the proxy to alternate request blocking.

Comment: So, no way to do it within selenium, only externally.

Comment: Selenium is a browser controller. You can dynamically set up a proxy to work with the selenium driver, as my example shows.